# Why is debugging of native shared libraries used by Android apps slow?

Tags: android, debugging, shared-libraries, gdbserver

I am frequently using gdbServer to debug a remote Android application. The area I have set breakpoints in is a shared library, written in c++.

Stepping through the code is extremely slow. Does anyone know why this is? My assumption is that the JNI calls to the library impose a large delay.

Answer (score 1):

> My assumption is that the JNI calls to the library impose a large delay.

When you are at a breakpoint, and execute `step` command in GDB, no JNI calls are actually happening (you are already in native code, and just continue until next line, or step into the next function, what's JNI got to do with it?)

Unfortunately, `step` could be slow even when executing natively; especially so for optimized code.

How could `step` command work? In theory, GDB could examine instructions for the current line, discover that there are no `CALL`s and `JMP`s, set a temporary break of the first instruction on the next line, and continue. That would be fast, but that's not how GDB actually works.

What it does instead is something simpler: it single-steps the processor, and at each instruction asks "am I now stopped on the same line I was last time I stopped?". If "yes", single-step again, until the answer is "no". You can observe this behavior by setting `set debug infrun 1`.

Depending on how many instructions your current line has, it could take a 100 single-steps to complete your `step` command. That can be slow with native debugging, it can become much slower still when using remote gdbserver, as every time single-step completes, GDB needs to ask gdbserver "where am I now". That's a lot of packets flying between GDB and gdbserver. You can observe these packets with `set debug remote 1`.

Thus the factors that

- GDB remote protocol is "chatty",
- that each packet needs to go to the device and back over a (relatively) slow link, and
- that a single `step` may involve a 100 of these

combine to produce the very slow `step` executions you've observed.

A possible workaround is to avoid doing `step`s. Instead, set breakpoints, and examine program state at each. Eventually you'll get to a breakpoint that is "downstream" from the bug (i.e. the program is already in a bad state). Now set a new breakpoint somewhere "upstream" from that, and look at the state there. Using "divide and conquer" approach, you'll pretty soon zero in on the problem.